# Como funcionar a OPENAI_API_KEY no zeppelin

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython-notebook, chatbot, api-key

Estou tentando integrar o chatgpt no zeppelin, eu havia testado o atual código via VSC e funcionou de forma normal, porém quando importei para o zeppelin está dando o seguinte erro:

```
%pyspark

import openai
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests

load_dotenv ("/home/zeppelin/.env")

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
# Define o input do usuário
user_input = "Qual a resposta para a vida, o universo e tudo?"

# Define a pergunta para a API do OpenAI
question = f"Eu: {user_input}\nBot: "

# Chama a API do OpenAI para gerar a resposta
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-003",
    prompt=question,
    max_tokens=2048,
    n=1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=1,
)

# Exibe a resposta gerada pela API do OpenAI
answer = response.choices[0].text.strip()
print(answer)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1391846875481352034.py", line 355, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1391846875481352034.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1391846875481352034.py", line 355, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O problema é que voce não chamou a função da maneira correta. O que você fez é invocar uma variável de maneira indexada (acessar uma posição de um array).

A forma correta, segundo a documentação, seria fazer a chamada do método  `getenv` que faz parte da lib `os`:

```
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
```

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/os.html).

---

Caso queira é possível fazer a chamada via index, (da maneira que está fazendo) mas vai ter que utilizar outro método. Terá que chamar o método [environ](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

Então teria que mudar o seu código para:

```
openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
```

Essa chamada possui o problema de lançar exceção caso chave do dicionário não exista.
Caso não queira que ocorra uma exceção (key error), pode utilizar o método:

```
openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
```

Caso não exista, irá retornar `None`.

---

Um exemplo de conteúdo do seu arquivo `.env` segue abaixo:

```
OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-...sc8v
```

Comment: Mas quando eu chamo dessa forma que você indicou, aparece o erro :

 TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable

Comment: cara, isso aí já é outro erro, provavelmente em outro lugar. E que não está relacionado com o erro inicial.

Comment: Ah ok, vou dar uma revisada no código inteiro aqui, Obrigado.

Comment: Eu utilizei dessa forma:
openai.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
E funcionou certinho, obrigado